# Cómo utilizar jasper reports en Yii2

Tags: php, jasper-reports, yii2

Necesito integrar la plantilla basic de Yii2 con Jasper Reports.

He seguido paso a paso las instrucciones de [JasperReports for yii2](https://github.com/chrmorandi/yii2-jasper)

1. Instalado JDK 1.8 en mi Debian 8
2. Configurado el classpath del conector mysql en /etc/profile
3. Añadida la extensión chrmorandi/yii2-jasper a mi composer y actualizado este

La función exec() de php está habilitada ya que la prueba siguiente me devuelve el usuario ...

```
<? echo exec('whoami'); ?>
```

La extensión chromandi recién importada efecctivamente aparece bajo /vendors

java -version dice 1.8.0_111

$CLASHPATH configurado y devolviendo /usr/share/mysql-connector-java/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar

En el fichero de configuración ...

```
'components' => [
    'jasper' => [
        'class' => 'chrmorandi\jasper',
        'db' => [
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'port' => 3306,
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'dbname' => 'acme',
            'username' => 'acme',
            'password' => 'acme'
        ]
    ],
    ...
]
```

He añadido un controlador tal que así ...

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use chrmorandi\Jasper;

class EstadisticasController extends \yii\web\Controller {

    public function actionIndex() {
        // Set alias for sample directory
        Yii::setAlias('example', '@vendor/chrmorandi/yii2-jasper/examples');

        /* @var $jasper Jasper */
        $jasper = Yii::$app->jasper;

        // Compile a JRXML to Jasper
        $jasper->compile(Yii::getAlias('@example') . '/hello_world.jrxml')->execute();

        // Process a Jasper file to PDF and RTF (you can use directly the .jrxml)
        $jasper->process(Yii::getAlias('@example') . '/hello_world.jasper', [
            'php_version' => 'xxx'
        ], [
            'pdf',
            'rtf'
        ], false, false)->execute();

        // List the parameters from a Jasper file.
        $array = $jasper->listParameters(Yii::getAlias('@example') . '/hello_world.jasper')->execute();

        // return pdf file
        Yii::$app->response->sendFile(Yii::getAlias('@example') . '/hello_world.pdf');

    }
}
```

y compruebo http://www.acme.es/estadisticas/index donde se supone que hay un ejemplo sencillo de jasper incluido.

El problema viene ahora. La aplicación se queja en la línea

```
$jasper = Yii::$app->jasper;
```

La salida indica ...

> ReflectionException  Class chrmorandi\jasper does not exist

¿Alguien tiene experiencia con esta extensión chrmorandi/yii2-jasper?
¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?
¿Alguna otra manera de integrar Jasper Reports con Yii2?

Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente la solución era cambiar

```
$jasper = Yii::$app->jasper;
```

por

```
$jasper = new \chrmorandi\jasper\Jasper();
```

No sé por qué en la docu de yii2-jasper está configurada esta línea así si no funciona. De todas formas basta con realizar la esta pequeña modificación para que lo haga.

Como la invocación

```
use chrmorandi\Jasper
```

no está funcionando correctamente tendréis que modificar Jasper.php en su función init por ejemplo tal que así

```
$componentes = Yii::$app->components;
$this->db = $componentes['jasper']['db'];
```

para que funcione.

Editar bajo /vendors no es algo que quiera hacer. Para evitar este tipo de "apaños" he sustituido la extensión de chrmorandi (hasta que se corrijan estos flecos) por la de [cossou/jasperphp](https://packagist.org/packages/cossou/jasperphp).

Hasta ahora la extensión de cossou cumple mis requisitos.

Espero que con este post pueda ayudar a alguien con mi mismo problema.